# Unable to install appcelerator CLI -Unexpect end of input

Tags: npm, appcelerator, npm-install, appcelerator-cli

Tried to Reinstall Appcelerator Cli 
after reinstalling Xcode 
but always having error 
I installed node with version v4.4.0

then every time i try to execute the following command in order to install appcelerator cli

```
sudo npm install appcelerator -g
```

It gives me the following error :

npm ERR! registry error parsing json

npm ERR! Darwin 15.3.0

npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "appcelerator" "-g"

npm ERR! node v4.4.0

npm ERR! npm  v2.14.20

npm ERR! Unexpected end of input

npm ERR! {"_id":"appcelera ........etc

with a very long json string.

Comment: Internet Problem Probably .
Tried from another network .
proceded successfully with all installation steps 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Problem Probably .
Tried from another network .
proceded successfully with all installation steps 
thanks